# Does AMAZON MQ provides TCP endpoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, activemq-classic, amazon-mq

I have created one broker on Amazon MQ and got a SSL endpoint on port 61617. I was looking for one non SSL endpoint as well (like we can have tcp on 61616 on Active MQ). Does Amazon MQ provides only SSL? Is there anyway, we can get the TCP endpoint as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AmazonMQ only provides SSL endpoint, it does not expose and TCP endpoint like activeMQ. But it works and connect equally well when you switch from activeMQ tcp endpoint to amazonMQ SSL.

For example:

> activemq.broker.url                   =
>   failover:(tcp://abc1.gogole.com:61616,tcp://abc1.gogole.com:61616)?randomize=false&maxReconnectAttempts=10
>
> amazonmq.broker.url          =
>   failover:(ssl://efg-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:61617,ssl://efg-2.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:61617)?randomize=false&maxReconnectAttempts=5

Any specific use case on why are you looking for TCP endpoint?

Comment: Thanks @anshul In my code, protocol to connect is hardcoded to tcp. So, i guess, it needs to be changed and as per your comment and my understanding I believe, something like tcp://efg-1.mq.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:61616 is not possible to achieve. Please correct me , if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: That's right you cannot use "tcp" instead of "ssl" in amazonMQ case.

Comment: @Nish Kindly accept it as a solution or up-vote if the answer helped.